# AceFEM: Tie - Option Issue

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I try to use the "Tie" Option of the SMTAnalysis[] function.
In general, I want to have some additional Nodes (two kinds of them) at certain (not all) coordinates tied and at some not. 
What I have is of course the coordinates of the points where I want to suppress tying.

```
<< AceGen`;
SMSInitialize[
"test", "Environment" -> "AceFEM", "Mode" -> "Prototype"];
SMSTemplate[
"SMSTopology" -> "L1",
"SMSNoNodes" -> 6,
"SMSDOFGlobal" -> {2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1},
"SMSNodeID" -> {"D", "D", "dD", "T", "dD", "T"},
"SMSAdditionalNodes" -> Hold[{#1, #1, #2, #2} &]
];
SMSStandardModule["Tangent and residual"];
SMSWrite[];
```

The element code will create three kinds of nodes ("D","dD","T").
In the following example I want to have them tied at the coordinate (2/3,0) but not at (1/3,0).
I coded a node selector which should do the job, as it works fine in the SMTFindNodes[] command.

```
<< AceFEM`;
SMTInputData[];
SMTAddDomain["test", "test", {}];
SMTAddMesh[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], "test", "L1", 3];
SMTAnalysis[];
n = SMTFindNodes[("ID" == "dD" && "X" == 1/3) || ("ID" == "T" && 
      "X" == 1/3) &]
{SMTNodeData[n, "NodeID"], SMTNodeData[n, "X"]} // TableForm
```

Still when using it within the above mentioned option, the behaviour is differently.

```
<< AceFEM`;
SMTInputData[];
SMTAddDomain["test", "test", {}];
SMTAddMesh[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], "test", "L1", 3];
SMTAnalysis[
 "Tie" -> {True, ("ID" == "dD" && "X" == 1/3) || ("ID" == "T" && 
       "X" == 1/3) &}]
n = SMTFindNodes[("ID" == "dD" && "X" == 1/3) || ("ID" == "T" && 
      "X" == 1/3) &]
{SMTNodeData[n, "NodeID"], SMTNodeData[n, "X"]} // TableForm
```

I would expect 4 nodes, 2 of each kind ("dD","T") at this position now, but it tied the "dD" anyway.
Anyone a suggestion for what I made wrong here? I don't feel very comfortable building this conditional when dealing with a larger number of coordinates.
Does anyone know a better way to handle this ?
Thanks in advance!
Sash